# How to withdraw a zoomed state window, until after the user has logged in tkinter Py3

Tags: tkinter

im looking for a way in which i can open a new window in the zoomed state once a user has logged in. This would be the main_menu, this is called from the top of the code (line 11). I am able to open this new window, or unhide it if the 'zoomed' state is not used. How would i go about opening/unhiding this window if it is in a zoomed state? for some reason it opens it up when the program starts, even without the user logging in if a zoomed state is used.

```
from tkinter import *
import sqlite3
import hashlib
import os

def main():
  root = Tk()
  root.withdraw()

  mainMenu = main_menu(root)
  loginWindow =  login(root)
  root.mainloop() 

class login(Toplevel):
  def __init__(self, root):
    super().__init__(root)

    width = 600 #sets the width of the window
    height = 600 #sets the height of the window
    widthScreen = self.winfo_screenwidth() #gets the width of the screen
    heightScreen = self.winfo_screenheight() #gets the height of the screen
    x = (widthScreen/2) - (width/2) #finds the center value of x
    y = (heightScreen/2) - (height/2) #finds the center value of y
    self.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (width, height, x, y))#places screen in center
    self.resizable(width=False, height=False)#Ensures that the window size cannot be changed 
    filename = PhotoImage(file = 'Login.gif') #gets the image from directory
    background_label = Label(image=filename) #makes the image
    background_label.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)#palces the image

    self.__username = StringVar()
    self.__password = StringVar()
    self.__error = StringVar()
    userNameLabel = Label(self, text='UserID: ', bg=None, width=10).place(relx=0.300,rely=0.575)
    userNameEntry = Entry(self, textvariable=self.__username, width=25).place(relx=0.460,rely=0.575)
    userPasswordLabel = Label(self, text='Password: ', bg=None, width=10).place(relx=0.300,rely=0.625)
    userPasswordEntry = Entry(self, textvariable=self.__password, show='*', width=25).place(relx=0.460,rely=0.625)
    errorLabel = Label(self, textvariable=self.__error, bg=None, fg='red', width=35).place(relx=0.508,rely=0.545, anchor=CENTER)
    loginButton = Button(self, text='Login', command=self.login_user, bg='white', width=15).place(relx=0.300,rely=0.675)
    clearButton = Button(self, text='Clear', command=self.clear_entry, bg='white', width=15).place(relx=0.525,rely=0.675)
    self.master.bind('<Return>', lambda event: self.login_user()) #triggers the login subroutine if the enter key is pressed

  def login_user(self):
    username = self.__username.get()
    password = self.__password.get()
    hashPassword = (password.encode('utf-8'))
    newPass = hashlib.sha256()
    newPass.update(hashPassword)
    if username == '':
      self.__error.set('Error! No user ID entered')
    elif password == '':
      self.__error.set('Error! No password entered')
    else:
      with sqlite3.connect ('pkdata.db') as db:
        cursor = db.cursor()
        cursor.execute("select userID, password from users where userID=?",(username,))
        info = cursor.fetchone()
        if info is None:
          self.__error.set('Error! Login details not found!')
        else:
          dbUsername = info[0]
          dbPassword = info[1]
          if username == dbUsername or newPass.hexdigest() == dbPassword:
            loginWindow.withdraw()
            root.deiconify()
          else:
            self.__error.set('Error! please try again')
            self.clear_entry()

  def clear_entry(self):
    self.__username.set('')
    self.__password.set('')



class main_menu():        
  def __init__(self, root):
    self.root = root
    root.state('zoomed')
    root.title("Main Menu")


if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Toplevel is good if you want 2 windows open, but that's not what you want is it? You want one window open, and then another window to open. So instead of defining 2 windows, it would be a lot easier to define a single window and then change it when the time is right:

```python
class Mainframe(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.frame = FirstFrame(self)
        self.frame.pack()

    def change(self, frame):
        self.frame.pack_forget() # delete currrent frame
        self.frame = frame(self)
        self.frame.pack() # make new frame

class FirstFrame(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master, **kwargs)

        master.title("Enter password")
        master.geometry("300x200")

        self.status = tk.Label(self, fg='red')
        self.status.pack()
        lbl = tk.Label(self, text='Enter password')
        lbl.pack()
        self.pwd = tk.Entry(self, show="*")
        self.pwd.pack()
        self.pwd.focus()
        self.pwd.bind('<Return>', self.check)
        btn = tk.Button(self, text="Done", command=self.check)
        btn.pack()
        btn = tk.Button(self, text="Cancel", command=self.quit)
        btn.pack()

    def check(self, event=None):
        if self.pwd.get() == 'password':
            self.master.change(SecondFrame)
        else:
            self.status.config(text="wrong password")

class SecondFrame(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master, **kwargs)
        master.title("Main application")
        master.geometry("600x400")

        lbl = tk.Label(self, text='You made it to the main application')
        lbl.pack()

if __name__=="__main__":
    app=Mainframe()
    app.mainloop()
```